# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Responsive issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Boostrap 4 navbar in Angular application. There is some responsive issues. The logo moves to right after a certain reduction in width but on other widths stays on left. And also how do I make the login and register button stay on right always?

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXdjLm) for the same. And the bootstrap code is as follows:

```
<div class="header">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.keyshot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/keyshot-6-logo-150.png">
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a (click)="goToDiv('features')" class="nav-link">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a (click)="goToDiv('exams')" class="nav-link">Exams</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a (click)="goToDiv('pricing')" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a (click)="goToDiv('app')" class="nav-link">App</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a (click)="goToDiv('contact')" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto d-block d-sm-none step">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/login" class="login re-hover nav-link">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/register" class="login nav-link">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto d-none d-sm-block step">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/login" style="color: #32c8fa" class="login nav-link"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="margin-right: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i><b>LOGIN</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/register" style="color: #32c8fa" class="login nav-link"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="margin-right: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i><b>REGISTER</b></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: _The logo moves to right after a certain reduction in width_ because the direct child of `nav` which is `.container` has a `media query` which change its width depending on screen width so it act like the logo is moving to right and the right elements are moving to left. _how do I make the login and register button stay on right always_ they are already placed on right on all view-ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is because of the padding of the toggle button in `.navbar-toggler`

remove padding with media queries and it will works

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-brand{
    margin-right : 0px;
  }
  .navbar-toggler{padding:0px;}
}
```

Comment: you suggest overwriting the bootstrap class with this? also what will be the exact media query i need to use?

Comment: I've updated css in my answer use it in your styles and here is codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYxxBz